# where do I set my own signature on DocuSign？

Tags: docusignapi

I have purchased the api service and passed the online review. Now I have a question that I need your help to answer. My program uses the simplest process.

1. The user initiates a server request on my website
2. Create an envelope on the server side
3. Create a receiver view on the server side
4. Jump to the docusign page for customers to sign
5. Call back my website address to sign in full

My question is, where do I set my own signature? Do I need to set my signature in the program? What should I do as best practice.

I tried setting the template
I'm looking forward to a place that automatically completes the sender's signature without requiring the sender to sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking forward to a place that automatically completes the
> sender's signature without requiring the sender to sign.

This cannot be done and for a good reason, if you can add any name and sign for them, then there is not evidence to prove that this person signed. A signature has to be a human activity that shows consent/agreement to some contract/set of documents. Therefore, DocuSign requires that the act of signing done by a human and cannot be automated.

Comment: What I mean is that the sender sets his signature in a certain setting in the backend management on behalf of the company, and then his signature can be seen on the contract.

Comment: even that cannot be done unless the recipient is in the same account as the sender. You have to make an API call for the recipient, not the sender, you cannot impersonate someone from another company/account

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I now want to implement the simplest electronic signature.

Party A: Steve, the company’s signing representative

Party B: The dealer who signed the contract with us

We integrate docusign through our website. What should I do? Please give me the detailed steps.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is a very simple solution but it does not include automatically signing on behalf of the dealer or Steve. Each of them have to manually sign. If that's acceptable (Steve an Dealer both have to manually sign) please ask a new question if unlcear how to do this. Are you writing code? what language?